# How to style form elements unobtrusively with JavaScript and CSS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, xhtml

How to style from elements unobtrusively in all browsers including IE6

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what you want to do? The very nature of changing the style of an element seems "obtrusive" to me since it will be very obvious.

Comment: I want to give good look to form elements like Select dropdown box, file upload box ,which are not possible with only css. also want to style other elements too. but if Javascript would be disable by user then form elements should look normal default

Comment: I posted an answer, but you should edit your question title to this "How to style form elements unobtrusively with JavaScript and CSS"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far i found this is best and works in IE 6+, safari 2+, firefox 2+

http://www.dfc-e.com/metiers/multimedia/opensource/jqtransform/
[image]
<sub>(source: [blogfreakz.com](http://blogfreakz.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/04/jqtransform.jpg))</sub>

Answer (score 4):

There are a few plugins that do what you want. Basically, you want to add special styling to forms via javascript + css, but want the form to function normally if javascript is disabled

Here are two such plugins, but I am sure there are more out there:

1. [Uniform for jQuery on Github](http://github.com/pixelmatrix/uniform/) and [The Overview](http://pixelmatrixdesign.com/weblog/comments/announcing_uniform/)
2. [FancyForm for MooTools](http://lipidity.com/fancy-form/)

Comment: Do u know any more jquery plugins. I do not use MooTools.

Comment: Sorry, I don't! Uniform was really shaping up to be cool, but I guess Josh got busy because he hasn't updated it since June.

Comment: Uniform is very cool, but in my case i can't any xhtml <span>Choose</span> and class or ID to form element. I need styling on default html markup of formelements

Answer (score 3):

This new plugin works pretty well and is more robust than uniforms. http://customformsjs.com/

Comment: I agree with this one, customformsJs is amazing :)

Answer (score 0):

Use ***class names*** for you elements for which you can't apply styles generally in CSS.

Comment: i can't add class to any form elements

Comment: @jitendra - you'll have to explain why. If you can't add class to the markup you are severely crippled and if you can't do that why on earth can you add JS or CSS?

Comment: @annakata - yes i can add external js and css but nothing as inline css class, inline style etc

Answer (score -1):

Use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/). Specifically the `toggleClass` function and then use CSS classes to style your forms. No plugin required. See [jQuery Attributes Documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Attributes).

If you want more styles, check out [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/).

Comment: is there any plugin to make this easily possible